# how can I render an HTML page with express and at the same time pass json data to that HTML?

Tags: angularjs, json, mongodb, express

how can I render an HTML page with express and at the same time pass json data to that HTML? I get the json data from a collection of a mongoDB database.
My router file for /solutions looks like this:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.solutions.find(function (err, docs) {
    res.send(docs);
  });
});
```

And in the AngularJS controller:

```
$http.get('/solutions').then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

I don't specify `/solutions` in the solutions file because I do that in my main server.js file.

I know this only sends the data in json format. How can I pass the json to HTML and display it at the same time?

the collection I get from mongoDB has only one field (not counting the id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample project to achieve this

Consider the following project structure

```
www/          
  questions.html  // questions angular template
  solutions.html  // solutions angular template
  script.js       // angular code
app.js            // main entry point
api.js            // the api endpoint
db-mock.js        // a mongo db mock for demo purpose
package.json      // app dependencies
```

### package.json

Initialize project dependencies with the following commands

```
$ npm init
$ npm install --save express serve-static
```

### api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('./db-mock');

router.get('/questions', function(req, res) {
    var questions = db.questions.find();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(questions));
});

router.get('/solutions', function(req, res) {
    var solutions = db.solutions.find();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(solutions));
});

module.exports = router;
```

### app.js

This is our main entry point. Express server and routes are declared here.

```
var express = require('express');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var api = require('./api');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Serve API
app.use('/api', api);

// Serve static files (our client-side code)
app.use(serveStatic('www'));

// Start server
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port %d', port);
});
```

### db-mock.js

As we don't need a real Mongo server to make an example, we simply mock it.

```
// Mock Mongo db
var db = {
    questions: {
        find: function() {
            return [
                {id: 1, name: "Why ?"},
                {id: 2, name: "How do I do this ?"},
                {id: 3, name: "What's up ?"},
                {id: 4, name: "Siri, tell me a joke"},
                {id: 5, name: "Are we alone ?"}
            ]
        }
    },
    solutions: {
        find: function() {
            return [
                {id: 1, name: "Triswarm"},
                {id: 2, name: "U-bam"},
                {id: 3, name: "Betacore"},
                {id: 4, name: "Qvotrax"},
                {id: 5, name: "Homezuning"}
            ]
        }
    }
}

module.exports = db;
```

### script.js

AngularJS module and controllers declaration

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SolutionsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/solutions')
             .then(function(res) {
                 $scope.solutions = res.data;
             });
    }])
    .controller('QuestionsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/questions')
             .then(function(res) {
                 $scope.questions = res.data;
             });
    }]);
```

### questions.html

The Questions client-side template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="QuestionsController">
  <h1>Questions</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="question in questions">{{question.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

### solutions.html

The Solutions client-side template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SolutionsController">
  <h1>Solutions</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="solution in solutions">{{solution.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

### Startup

```
$ node app
```

Open your browser at `http://localhost:8080/questions.html`, you should see 5 questions

Open your browser at `http://localhost:8080/solutions.html`, you should see 5 solutions

### Alternate solution

You can render HTML at server-side using a template engine, for example `ejs`. You probably don't even need angular anymore.

```
$npm install ejs --save
```

Add a `views` directory under project root where you'll put your server-side templates

```
views/
  solutions.ejs
```

### solutions.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><%= pageTitle %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%= pageTitle %></h1>
    <ul><% for(var i=0; i<solutions.length; i++) { %>
        <li><%= solutions[i].name %></li>
    <% } %></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Change `app.js` this way :

```
// Declare /solutions route
app.get('/solutions', function(req, res) {
    var solutions = db.solutions.find();
    // Use `solutions.ejs` template to render
    res.render('solutions.ejs', {pageTitle: "Solutions", solutions: solutions});
});
```

Now start your server with `node app` and browse to `http://localhost:8080/solutions`

Do the same for other routes like `/questions`

> This is a very simple example, read the ejs doc to match your needs :
>   https://github.com/mde/ejs

Comment: This works when there is only one route. In my application I have: `var appRoutes = require('./backend/routes/api');var solutions = require('./backend/routes/solutions');var questions = require('./backend/routes/questions');`when I try to render HTML on the /solutions or /questions route, and don't use res.render, and instead I use res.send I only get the data in raw json format

Comment: I'm trying to understand.. You want to use your backend (node+express) as an API server or as an API server plus an HTML renderer ? (html template would then be handled by a server-side template engine)

Comment: just as an API server. I have all the routes in different files, and I have more than one HTML file. I tried your solution and it works when I only have one HTML file(index.html) but if I want to use your solution(the app.js file) in a different file where I use router: `var router = express.Router();`, and I use another HTML file(not index.html), I only get as result the data in json format.

Comment: I've updated my answer, `/api` routes are now declared in a dedicated `api.js` file and you can call `/questions.html` and `/solutions.html` templates which call different api routes.
Note that it's just a simple example. If you wann use angular on client-side, you might consider using a client-side router to handle routes other than `/api`

Comment: @blooddrunk did it answered your question ?

Comment: yes, thank you. Both solutions work. The second solution worked for my project. I'm using Angular as client-side router but I was getting errors when trying to render the solutions route like in your first solution.